# Source-able/executable shell script in the POSIX shell language

Tags: shell

What's a good POSIX compliant way to make a script both *executable* (a function from the script gets executed) and *in-sourcable* with the `.` command (nothing happens except (at least) 1 function becomes available?

I've tried:

src.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh -eu
FILENAME=src.sh
f() { echo hello from f; }
case $0 in ($FILENAME|*/$FILENAME) f "$@";; esac
```

and then tested it with:

```
( PATH=$PWD:$PATH; src.sh; . src.sh ; echo ===; f )
```

This appears to work as expected on Cygwin, MacOS and Linux.

Any suggestions on how to improve it?